# PhoneGap Android childbrowser issue - Capital C in childbrowser.java?

Tags: android, cordova

Trying to make an app using phonegap 1.4.1 + phonegap's childbrowser plugin.
I've been following guides and digging a lot on the subject, but I'm stuck on an error I can't understand.

I've moved the childbrowser.java to the correct location and added this to the plugins.xml:

```
<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
```

added this to the androidmanifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But I get an error on the ChildBrowser.java on this line:

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser;
```

telling me that the declared package com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser does not match the expected package com.phonegap.plugins.ChildBrowser.

I changed it to capital C in childbrowser.java, and the error went away, but ofc, the plugin didn't work. 
i found this topic, discussing it, but no appearant fix
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/11993
I have tried renaming the plugin name in plugins.xml

Earlier, i was trying to whitelist some url's, but kept getting them blocked, so i'm thinking there's something wrong with my /res/xml directory? its meant to be projectroot/res/xml, right?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've created the package "com.phonegap.plugins.ChildBrowser" in your Eclipse project then you need to modify the plugins.xml line to be:

```
<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.ChildBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
```

to match the actual package of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the ChildBrowser java file is in the package you declared in plugins.xml, which is in root/res/xml/ folder.
2. You need to add the javascript file to your main page, so the page can call it's methods. Check that the javascript file contents are consistent with you java file location - for example the packages may be different.
3. Add the right permissions
4. Make sure you call the plugin from javascript the right way, for example in phonegap 1.3 it goes like this:

   window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc)
               {
               ...